# Biblatex, Biber pdflatex: undefined references

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I'm tring to use biblatex with biber (Miktex 2.9 32bit on Win7 64bit), but I can't get it to work:

Here is my MWE:

```
\listfiles                % shows used packages in a list in log file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2000,
  author  = {AuthorA},
  title   = {Title of Article},
  journal = {Name of Journal},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{author2000}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

saved as test.tex

then I run:

```
pdflatex test
biber test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

and I get after the last run:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
```

I did clear the cache (par-* direcory).
It does work when I run bibtex instead of biber.

the log file after the 3rd run:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.9.21)  21 SEP 2013 19:13
entering extended mode
**test
(D:\Temp\tex\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filecontents\filecontents.sty"
Package: filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaT
eX document
)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./test.bib'.


("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   [### CUT SOME STUFF HERE ###]
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   [### CUT SOME STUFF HERE ###]
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   [### CUT SOME STUFF HERE ###]
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   [### CUT SOME STUFF HERE ###]
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\germanb.ldf"
Language: germanb 2008/06/01 v2.6m German support from the babel system

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@austrian = a dialect from \language\l@german 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 102.
))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.sty"
Package: csquotes 2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
\csq@reset=\count90
\csq@gtype=\count91
\csq@glevel=\count92
\csq@qlevel=\count93
\csq@maxlvl=\count94
\csq@tshold=\count95
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks17

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.def"
File: csquotes.def 2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.cfg"
File: csquotes.cfg 
))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
Package: biblatex 2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex2.sty"
Package: biblatex2 2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/
AB)

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count96

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count97
\c@listtotal=\count98
\c@listcount=\count99
\c@liststart=\count100
\c@liststop=\count101
\c@citecount=\count102
\c@citetotal=\count103
\c@multicitecount=\count104
\c@multicitetotal=\count105
\c@instcount=\count106
\c@maxnames=\count107
\c@minnames=\count108
\c@maxitems=\count109
\c@minitems=\count110
\c@citecounter=\count111
\c@savedcitecounter=\count112
\c@uniquelist=\count113
\c@uniquename=\count114
\c@refsection=\count115
\c@refsegment=\count116
\c@maxextratitle=\count117
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count118
\c@maxextrayear=\count119
\c@maxextraalpha=\count120
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count121
\c@highnamepenalty=\count122
\c@lownamepenalty=\count123
\c@maxparens=\count124
\c@parenlevel=\count125
\blx@tempcnta=\count126
\blx@tempcntb=\count127
\blx@tempcntc=\count128
\blx@maxsection=\count129
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count130
\blx@notetype=\count131
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count132
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count133
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count134
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\shorthandwidth=\skip45
\biblabelsep=\skip46
\bibitemsep=\skip47
\bibnamesep=\skip48
\bibinitsep=\skip49
\bibparsep=\skip50
\bibhang=\skip51
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count135
\c@maxcomprange=\count136
\c@mincompwidth=\count137
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count138
\c@savedafterword=\count139
\c@annotator=\count140
\c@savedannotator=\count141
\c@author=\count142
\c@savedauthor=\count143
\c@bookauthor=\count144
\c@savedbookauthor=\count145
\c@commentator=\count146
\c@savedcommentator=\count147
\c@editor=\count148
\c@savededitor=\count149
\c@editora=\count150
\c@savededitora=\count151
\c@editorb=\count152
\c@savededitorb=\count153
\c@editorc=\count154
\c@savededitorc=\count155
\c@foreword=\count156
\c@savedforeword=\count157
\c@holder=\count158
\c@savedholder=\count159
\c@introduction=\count160
\c@savedintroduction=\count161
\c@namea=\count162
\c@savednamea=\count163
\c@nameb=\count164
\c@savednameb=\count165
\c@namec=\count166
\c@savednamec=\count167
\c@shortauthor=\count168
\c@savedshortauthor=\count169
\c@shorteditor=\count170
\c@savedshorteditor=\count171
\c@translator=\count172
\c@savedtranslator=\count173
\c@labelname=\count174
\c@savedlabelname=\count175
\c@institution=\count176
\c@savedinstitution=\count177
\c@lista=\count178
\c@savedlista=\count179
\c@listb=\count180
\c@savedlistb=\count181
\c@listc=\count182
\c@savedlistc=\count183
\c@listd=\count184
\c@savedlistd=\count185
\c@liste=\count186
\c@savedliste=\count187
\c@listf=\count188
\c@savedlistf=\count189
\c@location=\count190
\c@savedlocation=\count191
\c@organization=\count192
\c@savedorganization=\count193
\c@origlocation=\count194
\c@savedoriglocation=\count195
\c@origpublisher=\count196
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count197
\c@publisher=\count198
\c@savedpublisher=\count199
\c@language=\count200
\c@savedlanguage=\count201
\c@pageref=\count202
\c@savedpageref=\count203
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def"
File: blx-compat.def 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def"
File: biblatex.def 
\c@textcitecount=\count204
\c@textcitetotal=\count205
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count206
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count207
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count208
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count209
\c@smartand=\count210
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric.bbx"
File: numeric.bbx 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"
File: standard.bbx 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count211
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count212
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\numeric.cbx"
File: numeric.cbx 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'german'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.

("D:\devtools\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\german.lbx"
File: german.lbx 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
(D:\Temp\tex\test.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' not found.

No file test.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 22.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 22.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'author2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 26.

[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (D:\Temp\tex\test.aux)

 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 germanb.ldf    2008/06/01 v2.6m German support from the babel system
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
  german.lbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ***********


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7014 strings out of 493921
 113725 string characters out of 3149287
 501868 words of memory out of 3000000
 10260 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5179 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 843 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,35p,789b,1346s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\RafiK\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\
ecbx1000.pk> <C:\Users\RafiK\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\
ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 5256 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 25 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

could you please help me find the bug I have somewhere?

edit: added test.blg

```
[0] Config.pm:361> INFO - This is Biber 1.5
[1] Config.pm:364> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[134] biber-MSWIN:190> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[135] Biber.pm:327> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[258] Utils.pm:167> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.3
[259] Biber.pm:619> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[294] Biber.pm:2976> INFO - Processing section 0
[331] Biber.pm:3086> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
[337] bibtex.pm:889> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[339] bibtex.pm:764> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
```

Comment: Probably more useful will be the Biber log (`.blg` file): the LaTeX log says `No file test.bbl` so that is where the problem will lie.

Comment: You have a version mismatch: `This is Biber 1.5` whereas you want `This is Biber 1.7` to go with `biblatex` 2.7a.

Comment: edited the question.. It looks all fine as far as I can tell...
edit: let me check that..

Comment: That was it! thanks alot. I thought I could neglect that WARN, since it was not en ERROR.. Should I post an answer?

Comment: Seems like a good idea, assuming that you've actually solved the problem by updating

Comment: yes, it was the update that helped. I'll post asap (have to wait 8 hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Josef Wright:

### Problem:

Version mismatch of packages `biblatex`(packaged: 2013-07-29, biblatex 2.7a) and `miktex-biber-bin`(packaged: 2013-01-24; biber v1.5) from MiKTeX v2.9.4196

(Repro versions: 2013-09-13, installed 2013-09-21)

### Solution:

Update your version of [biber from here](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/).
Copy the biber.exe into `\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` (overwriting the existing one)

### How to prevent:

Check the compatibly matrix in the [biber doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf), section 2.3